# RC filters output voltage levels

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

How to calulate output voltage level (U2) for a frequency ten times greater than cutoff frequency? ]

for example :
U1(input voltage) = -14 dB?

[image: CR circuit]

Or in second case. What is the output voltage level (U2) for a frequency that is 10% of the cutoff frequency? U1 = -14 dB

[image: RC circuit]

Comment: Both will be about the same as the input voltage - maybe 0.05 dB lower.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens you must be reading a different question then.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens Andy is correct. I think you are reversing the high pass / low pass of the questions.

Comment: Yes I didnt see they were different.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens it also 20 log and not 10 log

Answer (score 0):

Well, solving for the first case. We have the following transfer function:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}=\frac{\text{sCR}}{\text{sCR}+1}\tag1$$

Using the fact that \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ for sinusodial signals, we can write:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{CR}\omega}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}}\tag2$$

We can find the cut-off frequency by solving:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\text{CR}\omega_0}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}\omega_0\right)^2}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega_0=\frac{1}{\text{CR}}\tag3$$

So, the frequency is given by:

$$\text{f}_0=\frac{1}{2\pi\text{CR}}\tag4$$

So, when we look at the dB-level at \$10\cdot\text{f}_0\$ we get:

$$20\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{CR}\cdot2\pi\cdot10\cdot\text{f}_0}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}\cdot2\pi\cdot10\cdot\text{f}_0\right)^2}}\right)=20\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{CR}\cdot2\pi\cdot10\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi\text{CR}}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}\cdot2\pi\cdot10\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi\text{CR}}\right)^2}}\right)=$$
$$20\log_{10}\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt{1+\left(10\right)^2}}\right)=20\log_{10}\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt{101}}\right)\approx-0.0432137\space\text{dB}\tag5$$